# Mysql event is not invoked

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

i have created one event which call to a procedure at morning 4.01 am each day. To test current event i change my system date to 2013-10-17 04:00:00 & wait for a minute so that event will invoke but it does not invoke.

What is the problem?
How to test event in mysql?

```
CREATE EVENT EVENT_NOTIFICATION
ON SCHEDULE
EVERY 1 DAY STARTS '2013-10-17 04:01:00'
COMMENT 'Insert Notification'
DO CALL sp_Notification();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When i change system date manually, mysql server must be restart then only event get execute.

Comment: You really shouldn't tamper with the system clock while MySQL is running, and if you haven't restarted since you last changed it, you should restart MySQL again.  The explanation for the behavior you observed is pretty straightforward, though -- the event scheduler doesn't sit and watch the system clock... it looks at the time, looks at the scheduled events, determines how soon the next one will occur, and then waits the calculated amount of time before waking up again to fire off the next event.

Answer (score 0):

Check the value of the variable `@@global.event_scheduler`, it must be in 1 or ON.

```sql
SELECT @@global.event_scheduler;
SET @@global.event_scheduler := ON;
```

For more information: [19.4.2. Event Scheduler Configuration](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/events-configuration.html)